# How to resolve "Plugin xxx.xxx.xxx.maven.plugins:build-audit-maven-plugin:1.2-SNAPSHOT or one of its dependencies could not be resolved" error?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, spring-tool-suite, maven-surefire-plugin

I'm getting the following error when I try to build my project with maven

```
Plugin xxx.xxx.xxx.maven.plugins:build-audit-maven-plugin:1.2-SNAPSHOT or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for xxx.xxx.xxx.maven.plugins:build-audit-maven-plugin:jar:1.2-SNAPSHOT: Could not transfer artifact xxx.xxx.xxx.maven.plugins:build-audit-maven-plugin:pom:1.2-SNAPSHOT from/to snapshots (https://example.com/xxx): PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target -> [Help 1]
```

I've seen other answers to similar questions but none of them helped or maybe they're a little different. Can someone please help?

Comment: Does the xxx mean that you censored the output?

Comment: Yes it is censored.

Comment: The error says that you have certification problems. I would talk to your company admin how to solve these issues.